# How can i convert a tuple into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, tuples

I have a dataframe, which i converted into tuples using:

```
tuple = df.applymap(tuple)
```

So that i am able to sort two columns at once. The output looks something like this:

```
tuple.sort_values(by = ['Name', 'ID'], inplace = True)
Name          ID               Issues
(Ben, )      (p,y,t,h,o,n)     (t,i,m,e)
(John, )     (i,s)             (i,s)
(Zack, )     (f,u,n)           (p,r,e,c,i,o,u,s)
```

I'm trying to make the ID and issues to be in a string format (time), (python), etc

I've tried converting into a list, but it just gives me a datafram of 2 columns, with the index column, and Name, ID, Issues as the values of the second column, so its not working

Would appreciate any forms of help

Comment: why can't you sort it prior to making it a tuple?

Comment: Could you add the values of `tuple` before applying `applymap()` method?

Comment: I couldnt sort it, there's an error of 'unhashable: list'

Comment: before applymap():

Name          ID                  Issues
Ben             Python          time
John           Is                   is
Zack           Fun               precious

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get your question. And as observed above, it is self defeating to split items and again eliminate the `sep`. Anyway, Does this help?

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('[,|\(|\)]', ''))
```

[image]

Comment: I was splitting the items so that i can sort two columns at one time, to make the dataframe hashable.
Becausemy values were all over the place, i was trying to sort the dataframe via Name and ID, but, then it were splitted up when i was trying to print the output
I tried your code, but it didnt worked.. 

tuple = df.applymap(tuple)
tuple.sort_values(by = ['Stn Zone', 'Stn ID'], inplace = True)
tuple.set_index(['Stn Zone'])
df_final = tuple.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('[,|\(|\)]', ''))

It gave an empty dataframe with just the column names :(